# What would be the best practice for creating an element with two actions?

Tags: selection, tree

*Context: The user must navigate through a tree structure and select any one item from it's contents (including its parents)*

I find myself coming up against this situation often. I have a component that requires two actions of the user. In this instance, the user needs to be able to expand all the parents and children AND be able to select(or highlight) them.

[image]

I am struggling to find any good examples of this so I thought i'd put it out to the community to see if there is anything I could do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a checkbox list should meet the requirements. This is a common pattern and should be easy to implement. Clicking on the container expands or collapses the node, while the checkbox is used for selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Navigation Pane" in Windows explorer seems a reasonable example of what you are trying to achieve. It looks almost exactly like your example screenshot, albeit with the arrowheads on the left instead of on the right. Click the arrowhead to expand/collapse, and the text next to it to select.